# Questions on rxDataStep when using 'transformFunc'

Tags: r, microsoft-r

The following R code is to add one column to the dataset and return the data.frame.

```
xdfAirDemo <- RxXdfData(file.path(rxGetOption("sampleDataDir"),  "AirlineDemoSmall.xdf"))
```

I add a print function to check the length of the vector.

```
f.append <- function(lst){
  lst$mod_val_test <- rep(1, length(lst[[1]]))
  print(length(lst$mod_val_test))
  return(lst)
}

df.Airline <- rxDataStep(inData = xdfAirDemo, transformFunc = f.append)
```

When I run the above rxDatastep , the print function in the 'f.append' function was executed twice and output two values. Can someone help me to understand how the rxDatastep works?

The result show as below.
[1] 10

[1] 600000

Rows Read: 600000, Total Rows Processed: 600000, Total Chunk Time: 0.651 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `rxDataStep`, it actually runs your code on the first 10 rows of the data as a test. If this succeeds, it then processes the entire dataset one chunk at a time.

If you don't want your code to be executed in the test run, you can check the value of the `.rxIsTestChunk` builtin variable:

```
f.append <- function(lst)
{
    # don't print anything if this is the test chunk
    if(.rxIsTestChunk)
        return(NULL)

    lst$mod_val_test <- rep(1, length(lst[[1]]))
    print(length(lst$mod_val_test))
    return(lst)
}
```

Comment: I want to build a classification model. I need sampling the dataset to model(70%) and validation(30%) dataset. The dependent variable is a binary variable(Y or N), and the ratio of Y/N = 1/5. I want to keep the two datasets (model and validation) the same ratio as the entire dataset. If the entire dataset is split to many chunks, in each chunk, the ratio may be not same as the original ratio. When I apply the function 'createDataPartition'(in caret package) to each chunk, it may not return the expected result. Could you please help me on this question?